# PHP code stop executing other php functions after function runs

Tags: php, function

So I ran into a sort of a unique situation, at least for me anyways. I have a PHP function that check to see if a user is logged in or not. It updates some database information and then based on if the user is a valid logged in user, it return true or false. Problem I'm having is when this bit of code runs, all other PHP functions that try and run after it doesn't run at all. I don't have any PHP errors or anything. I'm pretty confused.

If I could get some help figuring this out, it would be greatly appreciated.

So the login check function looks like this:

```php
  function loggedIn() {

    global $conn;

    if(isset($_COOKIE['SS_ID'])) {

        $rows = numRows("SELECT * FROM login_info WHERE login_info = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_COOKIE['SS_ID'])."'");

        if($rows >= 1) {

            $hash = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-", 157)), 0, 157);

            $query = query("UPDATE login_info SET login_info = '$hash' WHERE login_info = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_COOKIE['SS_ID'])."'");

            setcookie('SS_ID',$hash, $cookieTime, '/', 'domain.com');

            return true;
        }
        else {

            setcookie('SS_ID', '', false, '/', 'domain.com');

        }

    }

    return false;

  }
```

Again, no PHP errors from that bit of code at all, and it runs as expected. Though when I run another function after it, I get nothing. So here's the page that I'm running these functions on.

```php
<?php 
      // ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
      // ini_set('display_errors', 1);
      // error_reporting(-1);


    require './server/lib.php';

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://example.com/css/global.css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fredoka+One|Muli|Days+One|Noto+Sans+KR&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/js/global.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/js/main.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header">

            <div id="headerTop">
                <span class="logo">
                    <a href="https://example.com"><img src="https://example.com/images/example.png" /></a>
                </span>
            </div>

            <div id="navLinks">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="https://example.com">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://example.com/vocabulary">Vocabulary Words</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://example.com/quiz">Take a Quiz</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="navLinksRight">
            <?php if(loggedIn() == false) { ?>
                <ul>
                    <li class="loginBtn"><a href="https://example.com/login">Log In</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://example.com/signup">Sign Up</a></li>
                </ul>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="https://example.com/index?logout=true">Log out</a></li>
                </ul>
            <?php } ?>
            </div>
</div>


<div id="container">
            <div id="leftColumn">
                Left column here
            </div>


        <div id="rightColumn">
                right column here
        </div>
</div>
    </div>

    <?php if( user('permission') >= 3) {  ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/js/cpanel.js"></script>
    <?php } ?>

</body>
</html>
```

So again, the code works as expected where the if `loggedIn()` runs, but when I try and run the `user('permission')` it acts as if it's not even there. Though if I were to move the `user('permission')` before the `loggedIn()`, everything works fine. I've tried to just run a simple echo after the `loggedIn()` function, yet again it doesn't show any outputs on the page. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I'd be looking at your actual generated HTML to check this. So when you perform a view source in your browser what do you see?

Comment: Nothing. I already checked to see if maybe it was hidden on the page where I couldn't see it. Nothing is being sent out into the source code. View source shows nothing other than what is already being displayed on the page. No echoed text.

Comment: Ok well another "Lazy persons" way to debug without thinking too hard is to start placing a single line like exit("I get here - Line " . __ LINE __); without the spaces between the underlines and LINE, from somewhere at the start and keep moving it further into the code until it stops working.

Comment: Hmm.. Not to sure if I follow. Do I put the exit() inside of the loggIn(), or on the page with the html?

Comment: Well you start where it works and work your way down into the code until it stops working to find out where its got an issue...

Comment: Well that's where I'm confused. Because the actual loggedIn() runs completely fine when no other code is running after it. So there is no errors coming from the loggedIn(). So if I where to put the exit() inside of the loggedIn(), how would that tell me anything?

Comment: Well put it all back to where it doesn't work and start working your way backwards... Ok Plan B - whats in this function called user()? We don't have enough info to replicate your issue.  Better yet whats in lib.php.

Comment: Okay so I made a mistake. So checking back and trying again, it does appear that an echo will run. So, it must be a problem with user() function. Though the odd thing, is I try and run the user() before the loggedIn(), it runs fine. Though if the loggedIn() is ran before the user() is ran, nothing is returned.

Comment: Okay, I've figured out what's going on. The user() selects from login_info where the cookie SS_ID value login_info is in the database. In the field where the login_info is at, it contains the user_id. The problem is the loggedIn()  changes the login_info everytime the page is refreshed. So it's essentially coming back with no results for the user() because what was once in the login_info value no long is because of it being changed from loggedIn(). If that makes sense? Sorry for the confusion. And thanks you so much for your help.

Comment: Brilliant - You found the problem :) Yep makes sense. I didn't even get to using var_dump() and friends which sounds like you did in the end :) Good stuff